# Is there any issue if ternary operator is used in super() method

Tags: java, code-reviews

I am using a ternary operator in super () method of my code. While the code went for review, I got a reply that

> Strictly don’t use ternary operators in the Super() calls.

Is there any problem if we use ternary operators in the super() method?

Comment: Is it in the form of super((x < y) ? x : y)?

Comment: `public TestClass(String name, boolean hasName){`

`super(hasName ? name:"No Name");`

`}`

Comment: Does your code compile? It's hard to see what the reviewers are trying to point without seeing the code...

Comment: Yes, my code is using the ternary operators in super() and it is compiling fine. But the reviewer is not happy in using the ternary operator in the super() since it is a rule or something.

Comment: I would not reject a code review bevause there was a ternary, but the "correct" action would be to overload the TestClass constructor. One that takes a name and one that uses the default name.

Comment: @leon  But that will be just increasing the lines of code and making it more confusing for the developer to debug right ? And I am not getting why it would be the correct action to as per your statement :
**but the "correct" action would be to overload the TestClass constructor**

Comment: Do you need the parameter `name` at all when `hasName == false`? It seems to me that the problem is not about superclass constructor call or ternary operator. Your constructor method signature looks a bit strange. I would probably get rid of the `hasName`-parameter.

Comment: That is why correct is in quotation marks. What you want is different behaviour based on whether the a name is present. Currently you are doing this by using a boolean flag. That is not strictly OO, considering the behaviour you are trying to achieve. Overloading is what you want to use when you want different bahviour based on parameters. Making this change will move the ternary out of your constructor to your calling code `TestClass t = hasname ? new TestClass(name) : new TestClass()` More code does increase the chance of bugs, but more explicit code will make debugging easier

Comment: @come-from The code that I posted above is not the actual code.

Comment: @nigelthomas Ok. It's _very_ hard to see what the reviewers are trying to point out without seeing the actual code... :)

Comment: Item 1 of Effective Java says **Consider static factory methods instead of constructors** This problem seems like an excellent candidate to use that approach

Comment: Did you ask the reviewer what they were on about? They probably know better than we do what they were objecting to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I would reply to your reviewer and ask them to explain their comment. A critical part of the review process is understanding *why* code should be changed. Perhaps it doesn't adhere to the established coding standards, or similar code caused a problem in the past. Point is, ask why, in the spirit of understanding.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think the main problem is with the ternary operator.

My suggestion would be to overload the constructor like this:

```
public class TestClass: SuperClass {

    public TestClass() {
        this( "No Name" );
    }

    public TestClass(String name) {
        super( name );
    }

}
```